# Рисование на C++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, рисование

Есть код, который позволяет рисовать белыми кругами.

```
#include "Windows.h"

void DrawDot(HDC hdc, HDC hMemDC, RECT rcTarget, RECT client, HPEN hPen) {
    SelectObject(hMemDC, hPen);
    Ellipse(hMemDC, rcTarget.left - 5, rcTarget.top - 5, rcTarget.left + 5, rcTarget.top + 5);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, client.right, client.bottom, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HDC hdc;
    static RECT rcTarget;
    static BOOL fDrawEllipse;
    static HDC hMemDC;
    static HBITMAP hBMP;
    static RECT client = {};
    static HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_NULL, 2, NULL);

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &client);
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        hBMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, client.right, client.bottom);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hBMP);
        return 0;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        rcTarget.left = LOWORD(lParam);
        rcTarget.top = HIWORD(lParam);
        fDrawEllipse = true;

        DrawDot(hdc, hMemDC, rcTarget, client, hPen);
        return 0;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (fDrawEllipse) {
            rcTarget.left = LOWORD(lParam);
            rcTarget.top = HIWORD(lParam);

            DrawDot(hdc, hMemDC, rcTarget, client, hPen);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        fDrawEllipse = false;
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        DeleteDC(hdc);
        DeleteObject(hPen);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return (LRESULT)NULL;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_MENU;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Окно";
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClass(&wc);
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(L"Окно", L"Окно", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        500, 200, 400, 400, 0, 0, hInst, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

И все работает хорошо, но есть пару вопросов по этой теме.

1) Когда я нажимаю левую кнопку, то задний фон окна перерисовывается в черный цвет, как сделать, чтобы фон не менялся.

2) Как сделать, чтобы если я быстро мышкой веду по экрану, круги успевали рисоваться, чтобы не было пробелом между ними.

3) Как сделать более четкие круги вот именно в моем случае.

4) Все ли правильно и адекватно я написал. Может через WM_PAINT стоит делать? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот что у меня получилось на данный момент сделать. Код только оконной процедуры. Тк WinMain не менялся.

```
int x = 0, y = 0, x_prev = 0, y_prev = 0, N = 10;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HDC hdc;
    static BOOL fDrawEllipse;
    static HDC hMemDC;
    static HBITMAP hBMP;
    static RECT client = {};
    static HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_NULL, 2, NULL);

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &client);
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        hBMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, client.right, client.bottom);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hBMP);
        return 0;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        x = LOWORD(lParam);
        y = HIWORD(lParam);
        fDrawEllipse = true;
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hPen);
        Ellipse(hMemDC, x - 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, client.right, client.bottom, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        return 0;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (fDrawEllipse) {
            x_prev = x;
            y_prev = y;
            x = LOWORD(lParam);
            y = HIWORD(lParam);
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                int px = x_prev + (x - x_prev) * i / N;
                int py = y_prev + (y - y_prev) * i / N;
                SelectObject(hMemDC, hPen);
                Ellipse(hMemDC, px - 5, py - 5, px + 5, py + 5);
                BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, client.right, client.bottom, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        fDrawEllipse = false;
        x_prev = 0; y_prev = 0; x = 0; y = 0;
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        DeleteDC(hdc);
        DeleteObject(hPen);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return (LRESULT)NULL;
}
```

Переменную N я взял = 10 и теперь линия не прерывается, если только ну прям уж слишком резко не дернуть мышкой. И я думаю можно по разнице в координатах двух точек динамически вычислять эту переменную.

Все еще остаются актуальными вопросы 1, 3, 4.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое "более четкие" круги?

Comment: @MBo когда залез в Paint чтобы нарисовать еще 1 смайлик для сравнения, понял что в Paint карандаш работает так же. И понял что вопрос можно сформулировать четче. Как сделать рисование кистью, а не карандашом?

Comment: 1) ну так явно рисуйте фон тем цветом, какой хотите.  хотите прозрачности - тогда [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21668537/20468470)

Answer (score 0):

Рисование должно выполняться в WM_PAINT

Про мышку - надо записать и проверить позиции. Может, разрешения не хватает. А если хватает, то нужно из записанного списка позиций отрисовывать всё,что ещё не нарисовано, а не каждый раз по одному.

Судя по комментарию - действительно разрешение невелико, события мышки не так часто генерируются. Имея две точки A и B, можно сделать промежуточные `Px = Ax + (Bx - Ax) * i / N`,  (где N-1 - количество промежуточных точек).

При необходимости перерисовки нужно её вызвать мягким образом, задав InvalidateRect.

Стоит помнить, что WM_PAINT имеет один из самых низших приоритетов, будет выполняться не всегда, а когда есть возможность.

Comment: У меня была такая идея. Заносить позиции в вектор какой-нибудь и потом отрисовать, но разве когда я мышкой дергаю в WM_MOUSEMOVE не приходят уже разорванные координаты? Ну если например я резко с одного места перемещу курсор в другое, то все координаты курсора передадутся?

Comment: Да я только, что сделал чтобы при WM_MOUSEMOVE в вектор добавлялись точки, а при отпускании кнопки они все отрисовывались. И они так же с пробелами рисуются. Тут надо как-то от одной точки до другой точки рисовать несколько кругов, пока мои мысли на этой идеи остановились.

Comment: Да и хотелось бы, чтобы рисование линии происходит когда я веду мышку, а не отпускаю кнопку. То есть надо в WM_PAINT если например надо отрисовывать линию тогда когда у нас есть хотя бы 2 точки. И надо понять как мне изменять координаты x и y для кругов между двумя точками, чтобы они продолжали линию.

Comment: А можете прикрепить к своему ответу. Маленький пример с кодом. Вот что использовать вместо WM_PAINT тогда?

Comment: вместо WM_PAINT ничего не надо использовать. Почему вообще такой вопрос возник?

Comment: @MBo ну я уже не пользуюсь WM_PAINT, а так WM_PAINT имеет же наименьший приоритет. Например если использовать UpdateWindow вместо InvalidateRect то сообщение о перерисовки сразу попадет в WM_PAINT без очереди.

Comment: @AlexF уж слишком сложно. Мне нужно всего лишь рисовать на площади 64 на 64 разные рисунки без геометрический фигур всяких. А после получать массив с пикселями.

Comment: Оно имеет низкий приоритет не просто так, а ради корректного функционирования системы. Не нужно жёстко перерисовку требовать,  Invalidate вполне справится

Comment: Кроме того, приведённый в вопросе код порочен по сути, т.к.  контекст окна не обязан сохраняться. Положено на каждый WM_Paint получать BeginPaint и рисовать - так почему нужно идти наперекор системе?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105556/discussion-between---and-mbo).